# Printing on thermal Printer

Tags: printing, powerbuilder

I am using dw.print command and have a report to print with a width of 3 inches and no determined height. This is for a receipt. How do I set the paper size to follow the thermal printer installed. I cannot test this as I dont have a thermal printer here.

Can I assume to use Default Printer?

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to make the tests on the printer that will finally print the datawindow.

I had a lot of experiences that what i see on the datawindow is different from the printer document.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the print margins on the datawindow itself in the painter or modify them in the code during run time.  Look at the 'Print Specifications' tab on the datawindow painter.